# Variable in JSON string c#

Tags: c#, unix, interpolation

```
 Int32 unixTimestamp = (Int32)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
 Console.Write(unixTimestamp);
 var currentTimeUn = unixTimestamp.ToString();
string json = "{ \"Method\": \"GetShippedOrders\",\"Params\": { \"DateMin\": 1575158400, \"DateMax\": {currentTimeUn} }}";
```

How do I get currentTimeUn to be passed to DateMax?

Comment: just use replace method in string

Comment: @CodeCaster I have tried $, $@, {0}, currentTimeUn Get a missing close delimiter for $

Comment: Then that's a new question altogether. String interpolation is done in the form of `$"foo {bar}"`.

Comment: @CodeCaster " + currentTimeUn + " worked for me

Comment: but why are you doing your own JSON instead of encoding an object? always doing that will save you a lot of hassle in the long run.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I agree it's just for testing purposes really

Comment: Use `$` sign before opening the string with `"` or use `string.Format` method...

Answer (score 1):

**Solution using String interpolation**:

```
Int32 unixTimestamp = (Int32)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
var currentTimeUn = unixTimestamp.ToString();
string json = $"{{ \"Method\": \"GetShippedOrders\",\"Params\": {{ \"DateMin\": 1575158400, \"DateMax\": {currentTimeUn} }}}}";
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this the solution you have been looking for?

```
Int32 unixTimestamp = (Int32)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
 var currentTimeUn = unixTimestamp.ToString();
string json = "{ \"Method\": \"GetShippedOrders\",\"Params\": { \"DateMin\": 1575158400, \"DateMax\": {"+currentTimeUn+"} }}";
```

Comment: Thanks buddy just had to remove the braces and it worked thanks:)

Comment: But that's not string interpolation.

Comment: I know what are you talking about. 
Isn't it what you meant? -> https://riptutorial.com/csharp/example/49/string-interpolation

Comment: @BradPlaydon I have implemented a solution using interpolate, please see my answer no. 2